# Why doesn't BERT give me back my original sentence?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I've started playing with `BERT` encoder through the `huggingface` module.
[image]

I passed it a normal unmasked sentence and got the following results:
[image]

However, when I try to manually apply the softmax and decode the output:
[image]

I get back a bunch of unexpected `tensor(1012)` instead of my original sentence. BERT is an autoencoder, no?

Shouldn't it be giving me back the original sentence with fairly high probability since none of the input words was `[MASK]`? Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BERT (Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers) is a transformer-based machine learning model trained on a large corpus in self-learning fashion. It is devleoped to understand the context of a word based on its surrounding words in a sentence.

However, BERT is not an autoencoder as the prediction of non-masked words is ignored during training and does not reconstruct the input sentence. Rather,it generates a high-dimensional vector representation for each word in the sentence. These representations are context-dependent, means the same word can have different representations based on its context.

When user inputs a sentence to the BERT, it does not return the original sentence because it is not developed to generate text, but to understand the context and semantic meaning of the given text. BERT returns a set of vectors representing the contextualized meaning of each word in the sentence.

Comment: Ah, I must've confused BERT with BART. Do you by any chance know if there is anything special about `tensor(1012)`? Or is that just the logit that happens to get pushed when BERT decides to "discard" a piece of "useless information"?